# Syntax error in random number generator in python 2.x

Tags: python, syntax-error

Here’s my code:

```
#calling main

def main():

#importing and flipping coin

    import random
    decider = random.randint(1,2)
    Dec1 = raw_input('Decision one?: ')
    Dec2 = raw_input('Decision two?: ')
    one = Dec1
    two = Dec2

#this or that printer

    if decider == 1:
        print('You should do:', one)
    else:
        print('You should do:', two)’

#question to loop
def q():

    question = raw_input('Any more decisions? y/n: '):
    if question == y:
        main()
    else:
        break

q()

main()
```

I’m getting a syntax error on the ‘question = raw_input’, not sure why. I’m using a mobile python app that I think runs on 2.x because of the raw_input. Main works fine, I’m not sure what the question’s problem is. I’m still learning python so if anyone could explain, that’d be great!

Comment: Remove the `:` at the end of the line!

Answer (score 0):

remove the ':' placed at the end of raw_input() statement.

It should be just `question = raw_input('Any more decisions? y/n: ')`